# What happens when a Synthesist Eidolon is hit by control summoned creature spell?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, eidolon

When a [Synthesist](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/Summoner/archetypes/paizo-summoner-archetypes/synthesist) summoner summons their Eidolon, they fuse with it becoming one. As I have checked with [another question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/122270/23058), an Eidolon can be affected by control summoned creature spell, and the original caster can still potentially dismiss their summons.

However its a bit different in this case as the two are one.

The information that deals most with this is

> While fused, the synthesist loses the benefits of his armor. He counts as both his original type and as an outsider for any effect related to type, whichever is worse for the synthesist. Spells such as banishment or dismissal work normally on the eidolon, but the synthesist is unaffected. Neither the synthesist nor his eidolon can be targeted separately, as they are fused into one creature. The synthesist and eidolon cannot take separate actions. While fused with his eidolon, the synthesist can use all of his own abilities and gear, except for his armor. In all other cases, this ability functions as the summoner’s normal eidolon ability (for example, the synthesist cannot use his summon monster ability while the eidolon is present).

So anything that could target the Eidolon before, can still do so, but as the Eidolon is basically brain dead and just being moved by the summoner would it matter if the Eidolon is controlled or would the caster manage to gain control of the summoner and Eidolon with the casting of control summoned creature?

Answer (score 1):

I think the key parts of the Synthesist rules are -

> Spells such as banishment or dismissal work normally on the eidolon, but the synthesist is unaffected. **Neither the synthesist nor his eidolon can be targeted separately, as they are fused into one creature.**

This indicates that, although the Eidolon can be affected by some specific summoned-only spells, nothing else can target the pair separately. And Control Summoned Creature will ONLY work on the Eidolon, not the Summoner.

As a GM, I would rule that the spell does very little. I would allow the caster to dismiss the Eidolon, as the Synthesist normally could, but there would be no other effect, and the Synthesist could then resummon it as normal. Dismissing would take a Standard Action on the part of the caster, meaning they likely wouldn't be able to do it on the round they cast the Control spell.

Comment: Allowing the controller to dismiss the Eidolon is actually pretty powerful in this regard. Losing the fusion probably neuters the synthesist's combat ability and resummoning it is not necessarily trivial in combat.

Comment: @Carcer it also has a non-trivial cost for the caster of control summoned creature i.e. a Standard Action, which would likely need to be done on the round following the casting, following a failed save.

Comment: True enough - I only take exception at characterising the spell as "doing very little" when it is interpreted to allow you to basically turn off the Synthesist's main class feature.

Comment: “He counts as both his original type and as an outsider for any effect related to type, whichever is worse for the synthesist,” certainly might suggest that *control summoned creature* doesn't actually need to target the eidolon separately—it could target the whole synthesized summoner–eidolon pair. There is also a question of whether *control summoned creature* is one of the “Spells such as *banishment* or *dismissal*,” that work normally. Addressing these would improve your answer, I think.